# is nested choice state possible in spring state machine

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

Can we define multiple choice sequentially(nested if) with in a spring state machine like below

```
.withStates()
            .initial(States.READY)
            .fork(States.FORK)
            .state(States.TASKS)
            .join(States.JOIN)
            .choice(States.CHOICE1)
            .choice(States.CHOICE2)
            .state(States.ERROR)
```

How can i define choice state for below flowchart section[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer yes. Might be that this is not mentioned in docs but there is a test for this [testSubsequentChoiceStates](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/1.2.x/spring-statemachine-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/state/ChoiceStateTests.java#L126).